# Validating authorized & Unauthorized User (JWT ReactJS-Laravel)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, jwt

I'm currently doing login page. I have a problem with how to check if the user I login is valid or invalid before I set the token to the local storage.

**Error to my console:**

> POST http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login 401 (Unauthorized)

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401

**My Goal:**
To redirect to other pages if the user is valid then if invalid the user who enters will remain on the login page.

**I use Axios.post to make a request**

**I have here the handleSubmit button:**

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.post('/api/auth/login',this.state).then(response => {
        const token_id = response.data.access_token;
        const responsed = response.data;
        // localStorage.setItem('token', token_id);
        console.log(responsed);
    });

   

}
```

**And this is my function which is default from JWT documentation:**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
}
```

Comment: Are you using vue router?

Comment: I already solved the problem :) thank you Ross.

Comment: Ok Ross thanks i will add the answer

Answer (score 0):

To validate the user who login

I just add condition.

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.post('/api/auth/login',this.state).then(response => {

        const token_id = response.data.access_token;


        localStorage.setItem('token', token_id);
        var get_token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        if(get_token === null)
        {   
            return <Redirect to='/login'  />
        }
        else
        {
            this.props.history.push('/hiflyer-dashboard');
        }

    }).catch((error) =>{
        if(error.response)
        {
            alert('Invalid');
        }
    })



}
```